# When I use getRawSignature() to get the comment which has " in it, it is writing some improper string "â€œ"

Tags: java

When I use getRawSignature() to get the comment which has " in it, it is writing some improper string "â€œ". How to resolve this to get correct output? is there any alternate funtion WE have from IASTNode?

Answer (score 1):

`â€œ` is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) - almost always the result of having the unicode symbol `“` (U+201C, the left double quotation mark - *that is not a normal quote! It is slanted*), which you then convert into bytes by using UTF_8 encoding, and then you read those bytes back into a string but using some ISO-8859-X encoding. That's how you get mojibake: Take text, save in one encoding, read in another: Most non_ASCII has now turned into mojibake. You can't generally unbake this stuff, you have to get your encodings right, and read data in with the same encoding you wrote it with.

*However, that is probably not the root cause here*.

You've likely corrupted your source file and you pasted some source code into word, and then from word saved it, and then tried to read it with your parser. This borks your code, as word converts stuff. Such as converting `"Hello"` to `“Hello”`. Which you definitely do not want. You'll have to go in and undo all the damage done by hand, get a backup, or, if you're actually writing source code in MSWord, stop doing that right away - it is not a code editor and cannot be used to write code. Use notepad++, atom, eclipse, intellij, etc.

TL;DR:

1. Real fix: Stop using MSWord to edit source. It mangled it beyond suitable recognition.
2. If somehow you really wanted this (doubtful), find all places where you convert strings implicitly to bytes or vice versa and stop ever using those - you always want the explicit ones, where you specify charset. Then, specify `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. There are many such methods and you have no code pasted here so I can't tell you where you call one of these. An example is `new String(byteArr)` - that method is forbidden and must *never* be called. Call `new String(byteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead. You've got something like this earlier in your code, and that made a ticking time bomb. It went off when you invoked `.getRawSignature()`, but you're just seeing the bomb go off, you need to fix it where you created it.

Comment: I had updated my code with the suggestion, for UTF_8 resolved " .. but failed to convert " (closing inverted comma).. X” coming as X??

Comment: Your source file is already messed up, as it uses unicode slanted quotes instead of actual quotes. Fix it there.